# How to capture Data Truncation as an Error in informatica

Tags: error-handling, informatica, informatica-powercenter

i want  to make my session  fail when ever encountered data Truncation.

current scenario in my  session i am using Teradata TPT script to load data from source to target.

sometime due to datalength mismatch data truncate getting load to target without throwing the error.

EX : souce is VARCHAR(15) and target VARCHAR(10) in this scenario my session is throwing warning only and internally it  trim and truncate rest 5 character. and first 10 char load in to target.i want to  make my session to fail if any truncation occur.

as of now through googling i tried two otpion

1) Reject Truncated/Overflowed rows i checked in this  target proerty

2) Stop on errors  i did set to 1

but still it doesn't solve the probllem.please suggest any other way make it achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In the post session check for the number of rows in reject when you select reject truncated rows and mark fail parent.

Comment: even when i am selecting reject truncated rows option it is not  Rejecting the rows.all source data loaded in to target tables but being trunacated.

Comment: I overlooked that you are using Teradata TPT, Validate the code page used in database and Informatica, If that is not consistent. Using TPT makes the load faster but may have this issue for not being able to handle rejects,This might be a known issue, please check with Informatica for any way around. Similar issue exist on netezza due to fastload options.